# Удаление только слов

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Собственно вопрос в чем: В текстовом файле имеются строки вот такого вида:

```
Delphi1Prolanguage
Delphi2Prolang
Delphi3Proln
Delphi1
Delphi2
Delphi3
```

Как из этого списка удалить только слова **только целые слова**. К примеру мне нужно найти все строки где есть словосочетания **Delphi1, Delphi2, Delphi3** но если попадаются только чистые слова то их игнорировать.

**Результат должен быть:**

```
Delphi1Prolanguage
Delphi2Prolang
Delphi3Proln
```

Пробовала решить эту задачу используя Pos. Вот что я попытался сделать. Но при таком подходе **и те и те строки попадают в результат.**

**Пояснения к коду:**

```
Var
Frd1: TextFile // Текстовый файл
RS: String; // Строка
mas1 Array of String; // Массив
Fd: Boolean;

Ну и сам кусочек кода обработки....

   while not EoF(Frd1) do
        begin
          // Читаем строку из файла
          ReadLn(Frd1, Rs);
          // Ищем вхождение фильтрующей строки в массиве
          for i:=Low(mas1) to High(mas1) do
            begin
               Fd := (Pos(mas1[i], Rs) >  0);
              // Записываем строку в файл
              if Fd then
                WriteLn(Fz1, Rs);
            end;
        end;
```

Comment: Способ "по старинке": после того, как видим, что вхождение есть, проверяем 1 символ ДО слова и 1 символ после слова (длина слова+1). Если эти символы за пределами строки или это знаки препинания/пробел/табулятор, то удаляем (вырезаем) слово из строки. Способ "по новому": через regex делаем поиск-замену. Ищем "\bDelphi1\b", заменяем на пустую строку.

Comment: Можно ещё загрузить файл в TStringList (LoadFromFile) и с помощью IndexOf и Delete удалить ненужные строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i:=Low(mas1) to High(mas1) do
        begin
           if Length(mas1[i]) < Length(Rs)  then begin ///вот это добавить
             Fd := (Pos(mas1[i], Rs) >  0);
             // Записываем строку в файл
             if Fd then
              WriteLn(Fz1, Rs);
          end;
        end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Пробуй TRegex.Replace( RS, '\bDelphi1\b', '')

(в uses не забудь подключить RegularExpressions)

Вообще изучи RegEx - это пригодится в большинстве языков программирования для быстрых манипуляций поиска-замены-парсинга строк.